# DataTabe_RowDeleting, database not being updated

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, ado.net, dataset

My tableadapter's delete command is actually a stored procedure that is updating the row with the datetime the row was "deleted" as well as the user who did the delete in another column, because I don't want to actually delete the row but just flag it to not be included in future selects. I'm using my datatable's RowDeleting event like below, I'm not receiving any errors, the row is being removed from the datagridview bound to my datatable, although my two columns in the database table are not being updated successfully. Where am I going wrong?

```
private void PROCFixedIncomeTradesSelect_RowDeleting(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    AAMOpsDBDataSet.PROCFixedIncomeTradesSelectRow row = (AAMOpsDBDataSet.PROCFixedIncomeTradesSelectRow)e.Row;
    row.Deleted = DateTime.Now;
    row.DeletedBy = Environment.UserName;
}
```

Code I'm using to push changes to db is below:

```
private void pROCFixedIncomeTradesSelectBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveData();
}

private void SaveData()
{
    this.Validate();
    pROCFixedIncomeTradesSelectBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(aAMOpsDBDataSet);
}
```

Edit, day 2, I'm still hoping to find an answer to this question, any suggestions on things I can test to try to diagnose the problem? I did do a test of my update command, changed a value in a row of the datagridview, and clicked my save button, the value successfully updated in the database.

Comment: Are you ever calling `Update()` on your table adapter?

Comment: yes, i've updated my post with that code

Comment: try it with `Update()` on the tableadapter instead of going through the tableAdapterManager.

Comment: no, unfortunately that's still not working. commented out the tableadaptermanager line and added `pROCFixedIncomeTradesSelectTableAdapter.Update(aAMOpsDBDataSet);` instead, the behavior is the same

Comment: Have you tried following the dataRow's RowState throughout the process? Before the delete,after the the event, before the tableadapter update.

Comment: Added some Debug.Writelines at the beginning and end of my RowDeleting handler, as well as one in the RowDeleted handler. It reads "Unchanged","Modified", and "Deleted". Seems my issue may be in the tableadapter somewhere? Is there an event you'd recommend breaking on and doing further inspection?

Comment: I'm still unable to get this functionality to work correctly. Would my method of doing "deletes" be not recommended or go against a best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still confused why my other code wasn't working the way I desired, but I removed the event handler I was using and am now making my changes in the table adapter's RowUpdating event. This code works the way I want.

```
private void Adapter_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StatementType == StatementType.Delete)
    {
        pROCFixedIncomeTradesSelectTableAdapter.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters["@Deleted"].Value = DateTime.Now;
        pROCFixedIncomeTradesSelectTableAdapter.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters["@DeletedBy"].Value = Environment.UserName;
    }
}
```